# Webpack Entries and Dependencies configuration errors

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have multiple entries that all import jQuery. This gives me an error "Multiple chunks emit assets to the same filename", I'm assuming this is because of jQuery being imported in every file. I've read the Webpack documentation on dependencies, but it didn't work when I tried it the way the documentation has it. Here's my current config:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        content: './src/content.js',
        header: './src/header.js',
        frontpage:'./src/frontpage.js',
        footer:'./src/footer.js',
        remove:'./src/remove.js',
        results:'./src/results.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'content.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    }
};
```

From what I read from the docs, it should look like this, but it kept throwing errors saying:

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.entry should be one of these:
   function | object { <key>: non-empty string | [non-empty string] } | non-empty string | [non-empty string]
   -> The entry point(s) of the compilation.
   Details:
    * configuration.entry['frontpage'] should be a string.
      -> The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon startup.
    * configuration.entry['frontpage'] should be an array:
      [non-empty string]
      -> A non-empty array of non-empty strings
    * configuration.entry['frontpage'] should be one of these:
      [non-empty string]
      -> All modules are loaded upon startup. The last one is exported.
    * configuration.entry['frontpage'] should be one of these:
      non-empty string | [non-empty string]
      -> An entry point with name
```

Here's that configuration

```
const path = require('path');
const jquery = require('jquery')
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        content: { import: './src/content.js', dependOn: 'shared' },
        header: { import: './src/header.js', dependOn: 'shared' },
        frontpage: { import: './src/frontpage.js', dependOn: 'shared' },
        footer: { import: './src/footer.js', dependOn: 'shared' },
        remove: { import: './src/remove.js', dependOn: 'shared' },
        results: { import: './src/results.js', dependOn: 'shared' },
        shared: 'jquery'
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'content.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    }
};
```

what am I doing wrong?

P.S. I'm trying to keep it transpiled into one file.

[This is the document page I'm talking about](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#entry-dependencies)

Answer (score 2):

As described in https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10433 by Mr smelukov

> dependOn will be available since webpack@5.0.0-beta.14
>   webpack 4 does not support it